# How to improve the performance of random data lookups on an SSD disk when using mmap?

Tags: swap, mmap

When using mmap to map a file in Linux, a memory pointer is returned. If a byte is read from this pointer, Linux will read the entire page (usually 4096 bytes) containing that byte from the disk. This causes slow random access on the disk, which can be thousands of times slower than accessing data in memory. Since SSDs are already 100 times slower than memory, reading a few bytes may require reading the entire page of 4096 bytes, making it several hundred times slower. The swap page size in Linux is 4096 bytes and cannot be changed unless modified before compiling the Linux system. If the swap page size cannot be changed, how can we avoid reading the entire page of data from the disk when reading a few bytes using mmap? My ultimate goal is to perform random data lookups on an SSD disk at a speed that is 1/100th of memory, but not slower.

chatgpt says: One solution to this problem is to use the madvise() system call to tell the kernel that you will only access a small portion of the mapped file. This will prevent the kernel from reading the entire page from disk and instead only read the necessary portion of the page. The madvise() system call can be used with the MADV_RANDOM flag to indicate that the access pattern is random.

I checked and I don't think this is correct. MADV_RANDOM flag does not read a portion of the content of the swap page, MADV_RANDOM does not read any content from the swap page, but rather advises the kernel to randomly select which pages to evict from memory.